# Theorem regarding not uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions on $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ .Show that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $A_0 \subseteq A$ to a function $f:A_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ iff for some $\epsilon_0>0$ there exists a subsequence {$f_{n_k}$} of {$f_n$} and a sequence {$x_k$} in $A_0$ such that $|f_{n_k}(x_k)-f(x_k)| \ge \epsilon_0   \ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ 
I saw this as a lemma in Bertle Sherbert, and generally use this trick to disprove certain sequences are uniformly convergent.
But I am stuck how to prove this lemma.
I believe this is just a negation of the definition of uniform convergence.But I want to add more rigour.

Comment: It *is* just a negation of the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: Take a definition of uniform convergence, put a $\lnot$ before it, and then move that past the quantifiers (you probably know $\lnot \forall$ becomes $\exists \lnot$ etc.). Then pick a sequence.